# can not get image data in react + typescript + vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, vite, src

I have a vite + react + typescript project

while rendering list of items with map
there isn't any problem with string type data
but i have problem with img source that is local

shows the error:
Type '{ client: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2276, 9): The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes, HTMLImageElement>'
(property) React.ImgHTMLAttributes.src?: string | undefined

```js
import { Content } from "./Content";


export default function Hero() {
  return (
    <div className="py-14 sm:py-0 md:h-screen w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-evenly text-gray-300">
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center">
        {Content.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`w-11/12 md:w-[45%] lg:w-[29%] md:border-[1px] border-gray-800 border-b-[1px] last:border-b-0 md:last:border-b-[1px] lg:last:border-b-0 px-5 py-2 2xl:py-8 ${removeFeatBoreder(
              index
            )}`}
          >
            <div className="flex">

>! problem is here: item.icon
              <img src={item.icon} alt={item.alt} />

              <h3 className="text-blue-20 py-2 text-xl ">{item.title}</h3>
            </div>
            <p className="text-base xl:text-lg text-justify text-gray-300">
              {item.description}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
`
```

```js
import client from "../../assets/image/networking.png";

export const Content = [
  {
    icon: { client },
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
    {
    icon: { client },
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    icon: { client },
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  
];
```

Answer (score 1):

you've wrapped the item.icon in an object inside the Content array. You should directly assign the image source as a string, not as an object. Here's how you should define your Content array:

```
import client from "../../assets/image/networking.png";

export const Content = [
  {
    icon: client, // Use the image source directly, not as an object
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    icon: client, // Use the image source directly, not as an object
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    icon: client, // Use the image source directly, not as an object
    alt: "development",
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
];
```

By making this change, you're assigning the image source as a string, which is what the  attribute expects, and the error should be resolved